# Duplicate modules in nested structure of node module dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

When you do a npm install in your node project, it installs all the node modules mentioned in the package.json. The installed module's dependencies are in turn installed in their own folders. 
 I think this structure gives rise to a lot of duplicate code/modules. So would it not be a good idea if all the project dependencies are installed in one folder(modulename-version) and other modules refer to this folder. Please suggest.

Comment: Perhaps [`npm dedupe`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-dedupe.html).

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe